# Return number of nodes with 2 children

Tags: java, tree

I am working on a method that is supposed to return the number nodes in a tree that have two children. Here's what I have so far...

```
public int twoChild(TreeNode<Integer> root){
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    else if (root.left != null && root.right != null)
        int leftTwoChild = twoChild(root.left);
        int rightTwoChild = twoChild(root.right);
        return 1 + leftTwoChild + rightTwoChild;
```

I don't think I quite have it but I may have the right idea. If anyone could guide me along on how to do this I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Please stop editing the original question, it doesn't make sense to fix the code in the question, it invalides the answers. I'm reverting it to the original code, you already got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test each subtree separately. The base case happens when the *current* tree has both children, and we count it as one for the final result - but anyway we must keep traversing the rest of the tree. This is what I mean:

```
public int twoChild(TreeNode<Integer> root) {

    // base case: tree is empty
    if (root == null) return 0;

    // base case: tree has both children, or not    
    int count = root.left != null && root.right != null ? 1 : 0;

    // recursive cases: traverse both subtrees, accumulating result
    count += twoChild(root.left);
    count += twoChild(root.right);

    // return result of recurring on both subtrees
    return count;

}
```

Comment: Okay I see what you did. I updated the code in my question to try and adjust what I had to the method that you used. Now most of the examples I have done before use separate variables for the left and right, not just a single counter for all so I kept that. Is there a better way of doing it where I do it like my example where I have a left integer and a right integer?

Comment: It's just a matter of style, it doesn't change the result... but you could store the result of each recursive call in a separate variable and then add the three variables at the end: `count`, `countLeft`, `countRight`.

Comment: Alright so what I have in the question now makes sense and would properly work?

Comment: @MirrandaRyan no, it won't work, because you declared the variables in the wrong places. Test it, try to compile it and it'll fail.

Comment: I don't have an IDE in front of me at the moment I'm just doing this on paper. I don't see the issue...

Comment: 1) You didn't declare `count`, or `counter` 2) `if (root.left != null)` and `if (root.right != null)` are not necessary and should be deleted 3) if you don't delete them, at least declare the `leftTwoChild` and `rightTwoChild` variables _before_ the `if`, otherwise you won't be able to use them _after_ it. Please, test this with an IDE.

Comment: Alright well I think I did it correctly in the code before you edited it back. I initialized the counter at the beginning like you suggested and go rid of the two if statements so I see no more issues!

Comment: I guess so, time to test it on a real IDE ;) (I'm not an IDE, neither is Stack Overflow. Please always have an IDE in hand, when asking questions)